# Base path about swagger project

Tags: spring, swagger

I started to learn swagger in May 8th and completed my first project with swagger in today.

The page occurred but has a fatal problem that the base path of project didn't show ![enter image description here][1]and api list occurred error like(I don't have enough reputation so I describe the error):

expect Request URL is ：http://localhost:8080/TestFF/addUser?postData=11

now : http://localhost:8080/addUser?postData=11

I try about two or three ways to config the project but still without base path.
My configuration just like:

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>apidoc</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
        <param-value>TestFF.root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springMVC.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xls</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.doc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- 字体相关  开始 -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.eot</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.svg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.ttf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.woff</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.woff2</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- 字体相关  结束 -->

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

I'm not so sure weather if this problem relate to controller or not so I will paste the code for you if it's necessary.

thx and have a good day.

Comment: You neglected to mention which library you use to generate the Swagger documentation, and which version of that library.

Comment: Actually,I don't even have enough to submit two link,so the maven property is :[link] <dependency<groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId><artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId><version>1.0.2</version></dependency><properties><jackson.version>2.4.4</jackson.version><urlrewrite.version>4.0.4</urlrewrite.version></properties>

Comment: Since this is probably a new integration, please upgrade to https://github.com/springfox/springfox which is the new version of swagger-springmvc. They also have extensive documentation that should help you out.

Comment: I still can't fix this problem,but thanks a lot any way..........